# What is the reason of this crash?

Tags: ios, memory-management, crash

I received a crash. What is the reason of this crash?

[image]

Comment: You are dereferencing a pointer (in this case `delegate`) to an already deallocated object.

Comment: have you tried to caught the exception? what kind of the exception have you caught?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely your `delegate` object was deallocated and you're trying to send message to deallocated instance. Running your app with zombies enabled may help to diagnose that issue.

To enable zombies go to Product/Edit scheme in menu and check "Enable Zombie Objects" checkbox:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

i have met this problem . maybe your controller is destroied which contains the delegate. you will set the delegate=nil when your controller release. for example :write this :self.delegate=nil; int the -(void)delloc method of controller